# Align Buttons to left, center and right in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing some pages using bootstrap. I have these three buttons in the bottom of form. Left, right buttons are perfectly aligned but Cancel button not aligned to center. Please help. Here is the code:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success float-left">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" style="margin:auto">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Commit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>

  </div>
```

UPDATED:
Tried the first answer. It's still not giving me correct answer.
Output attached:[After trying first answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoLjQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Since you want all 3 buttons in one row, grouping them under 3 different "col-12" divs will not work. Either rename all "col-12" divs with "col-4":

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success float-left">
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" style="margin:auto">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
      <input type="submit" value="Commit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>

</div>
```

Or bring all 3 buttons under 1 div with class="col" with an additional class "d-flex justify-content-between" which makes it looks better and more cleaner than the previous:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-between">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success float-left">
    
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" style="margin:auto">Cancel</a>
    
      <input type="submit" value="Commit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>

</div>
```

**Original Answer**

You can use flex utilities to achieve this. Here are the missing classes in your code

```
d-flex justify-content-center
```

Here is the full code with the missing classes applied to the second col-12

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success float-left">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" style="margin:auto">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Commit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, Cancel button center aligned but all the 3 buttons are coming as ladder. not working for me.

Comment: @Shrey Sorry what do you mean coming as a ladder?? Could you share a screen shot

Comment: yeah sure. just a minute , updating in question

Comment: attached snapshot @ranul

Comment: @Shrey I don't see anything wrong with it. Isn't that what you wanted? Or do you want all 3 buttons in one row?

Comment: Yes i need in one row. As it doesn't look nice this way.

Comment: @Shrey In that case using col-12 on each button will not work. Either replace them all with col-4 or bring all 3 buttons inside one div with "col" class. I have updated my answer.

Comment: col-4 helped me with three buttons , merging all into single col helped me with 4 buttons scenario.

Comment: @Shrey I'm glad it worked out for you. As additional info, a col has 12 parts, so if you want to have 3 buttons, divide 12/3=4. So use each button in a col-4 div. If you want to have 4 buttons, 12/4=3, so use each button in a col-3 div. It's really simple. Or just stick to one col and use flex utilities :D

Comment: wow. thanks for the input. I will remember this always. Infact this helped me just now with two buttons. thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
/* please use this updated code */ 
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success float-left">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" style="margin:auto">Cancel</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Commit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
      </div>

  </div>
```

otherwise if you want to change in structure for all three button in 3 column , 1 row then review this answer given here: [How to align button to center using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183096/how-to-align-button-to-center-using-bootstrap)

Comment: @shrey you must use class="col-4" instead of col-12 to see all button in 1 row

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. col-4 helped me . +1 for your comment :)

Comment: if it resolved your issue then please mark this answer as resolved so other can try if same issue happen with them